# Rails Routes missing prefix for resources post route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a new controller and actions for a new model. I have setup the rails routes like below:

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :universes
    end
  end
```

I am trying to write up some RSpec tests using the path helpers (ex. `get(api_v1_universe_path(universe.id))`). When I go to look at the post route for invites the route is missing the prefix as shown here:

```
                                         POST     /api/v1/universes(.:format)                                                                       api/v1/universes#create
                     new_api_v1_universe GET      /api/v1/universes/new(.:format)                                                                   api/v1/universes#new
                    edit_api_v1_universe GET      /api/v1/universes/:id/edit(.:format)                                                              api/v1/universes#edit
                         api_v1_universe GET      /api/v1/universes/:id(.:format)                                                                   api/v1/universes#show
```

I know I can manually add a line like `post "/", to: "universe#create", as: "create"` to get a route with a prefix. However, I wanted to know what was causing prefix to be missing from the post route so I can possibly fix that instead?

Comment: Its not broken. You don' t have a `post "/", to: "universe#create", as: "create"` path helper in Rails because its not needed. You simply create a resource by sending a request to the collection path (` `api_v1_universe_path` - `/api/v1/universes`). The path helpers are not actually concerned with the HTTP method. Rather each resource just has a collection path, a member path and the new / edit actions which are just used to render forms and which are often omitted in APIs. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: Thank you for the information. That makes more sense now. I misunderstood how the path helpers were working.

Comment: In a request spec you would test creating a resource with `post api_v1_universes_path, params: { ... }`.